# Resharper or CodeRush - change flag from negative to positive

Tags: resharper, coderush

I have a class that has negative flag ("DoNot{Action}"). I would like to change this flag to positive "Do" and change all checks in the code, basically negating them. Is there such refactoring?

Here is an example. If I change the flage DoNotFilter to DoFilter all code that looks at this flag should change accordingly.

```
public bool DoNotFilter
{get;private set;}
```

changes to

```
public bool DoFilter
{get;private set;}
```

so

```
if (attribute.DoNotFilter == true)
```

need to change to

```
if (attribute.DoFilter == false)
```

Comment: So you want to rename a field and flip all boolean references to it? I'm not aware of either product providing that functionality.

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I inherited some code and it just does not make sense with negative flag.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get the Inline Property refactoring in ReSharper to do what you want. I'm not sure if it will work with attributes, though.

Example:

```
public bool DoNotFilter
{ get; private set; }

public void Foo()
{
    if (DoNotFilter == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aha!");
    }
}
```

Now change to:

```
public bool DoFilter
{ get; private set; }

public bool DoNotFilter
{ get { return !DoFilter; } }
```

Now refactor DoNotFilter and Inline Property:

```
public void Foo()
{
    if (!DoFilter == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aha!");
    }
}
```

If you try this, be sure to check everything in to source control first! :) No warranties!

You can also Remove redundant comparision to get the if down to:

```
if (!DoFilter)
```

Comment: Thanks, I might try this.  Attribute was just an example, no attributes(annotations) involved

Comment: Yes it is all in one solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio Find and Replace dialog.  To lunch the dialog press Ctrl+H.

Make sure that "Use" check box is checked and in dropdown list "Regular expression" is selected.  I also would check "Search hidden text" and "Search up" check boxes.

In "Find what" type:  ***`<DoNot{:i+}`***

In "Replace with" type: ***`Do\1`***

It will remove "Not" In all occurrences of DoNotXXX.

Next let replace

```
if (attribute.DoFilter == true)
```

with

```
if (attribute.DoFilter == false)
```

If you closed Find and Replace dialog, press Ctrl+H again.

In "Find what" type: ***`<Do{:i+} == true`***

In "Replace with" type: ***`Do\1 == false`***

Comment: Vadim, thanks for your answer but the code above was just an example, and it is not as straight forward as above.